# Google Chrome adjust volume per tab

Tags: google-chrome, audio

Is it possible to adjust the volume of individual tabs in Google Chrome?

I've found [an extension that allows the volume to be muted](https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/mutetab/acofndgbcimipbpeoplfjcapdbebbmca), but it does not allow variable volumes.

**UPDATE**
Years after asking this question, it looks like a solution is finally available!!! [@peta-sittek](https://superuser.com/users/218892/peta-sittek) created an extension to perform this exact function!

Answer (score 45, accepted):

Sounds like Volume Master (Chrome extension) does exactly what you want: https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/volume-master/jghecgabfgfdldnmbfkhmffcabddioke

I am the author of this product.

Comment: Exactly what I needed.  Great extension, thanks for making this great extension!

Comment: Nice, Jesus cries.

Comment: @Peta Sittek : How to enable this for all tabs (including new tabs) automatically?.. I just want to avoid for raising the volume for an each tab individually..

Answer (score 5):

You can active one of chromes flags on chrome://flags

Simply enable the called: Tab audio muting UI control. This works for Mac, Windows, Linux, Chrome OS.

Then if you're using an old browser restart Chrome but on newer ones simply right click on the tab and the option to mute the tab should be there.

Reference: http://www.omgchrome.com/how-to-enable-tab-mute-chrome-feature/

Comment: The question specifically asks for variable volume control rather than just muting, though.

Answer (score 1):

You could run Chrome Canary at the same time as Chrome; and then use the Windows volume mixer to turn up or down the volume for either app, independently.

https://www.google.com/intl/en/chrome/browser/canary.html

Answer (score 0):

Unless you break each tab into a separate browser, it is not possible, as windows sound control will just see chrome as one browser, not the multiple tabs within the browser.

Comment: Breaking it into another window didn't work for me - it still only has one Chrome option in the Windows volume mixer

Comment: Chrome could indeed contain a per-tab volume control, as it already needs to mix sound playing in parallel tabs, also scaling these based on preset volume, seems to be totally doable... So it is not a requirement for windows/OS sound control to see each tab...

Answer (score 0):

This doesn't address your question *exactly*, but it's as close as I can get. Considering it's been over three years since this was posted and there isn't a better solution, this is probably the best we can do. This is, essentially, an expansion on Rowe's solution.

You can't.

Sorry, but them's the breaks. But what you *can* do (at least in windows) is individually control the volumes of different running programs. So if instead of visiting different websites on different tabs, you visit them with different *applications*, you can control the volume by clicking the "speaker" icon on the windows taskbar and then clicking "mixer". For example, visit one website in chrome, and the other in firefox or IE. Rowe suggested installing chrome canary as your second browser, but any browser application will work.

Here's a step-by-step for accessing the mixer in windows 7:

http://www.thewindowsclub.com/the-new-windows-7-volume-mixer-control